# jquery.validate strange behavior

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have noticed strange behavior on jquery.validate in asp.net mvc

My model field contains field with `StringLength`attribute:

```
[StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Cannot be longer than 200 characters.")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

And View:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { })
<div class="form-group formgroup-custom">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Name, 2, 1, new { @class = "form-control"  })
</div>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger error-custom" })
```

So now if I click on my `TextArea` and enter 201 chars no error occurs, then on lose focus (lets say click on other field) error message appears. Then I get back to my `TextArea` delete content under 200 chars, error message hides and the difference is that after entering 201 char error shows automaticly without need of loosing focus.
It looks like first validation check is on some `loosing focus` event and then on second time it checks on `keye up`.

So my question is if `jquery.validate*` have some bug or if it possible that some other script broke it up somehow.

Framework:
.NET 4.6

Comment: That's the default behavior - refer [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), in particular the section titled _A few things to look out for when playing around with the demo_

Comment: Thanks! This page can be handy

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of jquery validate.

If you would like to validate only on the form submit, set 'onkeyup','onclick' and 'onfocusout' to 'false':

```
$("#form").validate({
   onfocusout: false,
   onkeyup: false,
   onclick: false
})
```